# Count total time diffrence with single query

Tags: sql-server, time, count, group-by

I have a data from database Like this :

```
HDiffrence  MDiffrence          Interv
      2      14          2 Hours 14 Minutes 
      0      4           0 Hours 4 Minutes
```

so i need to convert both of H and M into time format and I do some logic thing in other query

I do some check like this, here's to check if HH:MM is more than 15 minutes:

```
count((select(case when((select convert(time,(HDiffrence +':'+MDiffrence),114)) > ((select convert(time,('00' +':'+'15'),114))) )then 1 when ((select convert(time,(HDiffrence +':'+MDiffrence),114)) is null)  then null else 0 end)))
```

and I put the check into :

```
select contractor , COUNT(pm.PantauID) as total ,
count((select(case when((select convert(time,(HDiffrence +':'+MDiffrence),114)) > ((select convert(time,('00' +':'+'15'),114))) )then 1 when ((select convert(time,(HDiffrence +':'+MDiffrence),114)) is null)  then null else 0 end)))
   from Pantau p
left join PantauMSG pm
on p.PantauID = pm.PantauID
where PantauType = 'PT2' and PantauStatus <> 'PS1' and  
(CAST(SCH_DATE AS DATE) = (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), 103) AS Expr1))
group by  CONTRACTOR
```

but yes, absoulutely get error :

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

so based on my logic to check the time , is it other way more simplified to count value more than 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you're just working with integer values for Hours and Minutes, just use basic maths instead of converting it to a Time value:

```
declare @hours int = 1
declare @mins int = 35
declare @total_mins int = (@hours * 60) + @mins

select @total_mins - 15
```

Then use it something like this:

```
select contractor, COUNT(pm.PantauID) as total, sum(HDiffrence) as Hours, 
       sum(MDiffrence) as Minutes, sum(HDiffrence) * 60 + sum(MDiffrence) as TotalMinutes
from Pantau p
left join PantauMSG pm
on p.PantauID = pm.PantauID
where PantauType = 'PT2' and PantauStatus <> 'PS1' and  
(CAST(SCH_DATE AS DATE) = (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), 103) AS Expr1))
group by  CONTRACTOR
```

Comment: Im sorry but by your query I get total for minutes, all i want is count the total of time with 15 min diffrence

Comment: @Sabilv should have stated that this doesn't directly answer the question but it simplifies your query to remove the time conversion factor

Comment: yep I got an Idea from your query the conversion is more simplified

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on Tanner Idea I change my query and yes, finally it works:

```
 select contractor , COUNT(pm.PantauID) as total ,
        count(case when ((convert(int, HDiffrence)* 60 )+convert(int,MDiffrence)) > 15 then ((convert(int, HDiffrence)* 60 )+convert(int,MDiffrence)) else null end) as Morethan15,
        count(case when ((convert(int, HDiffrence)* 60 )+convert(int,MDiffrence)) < 15 then ((convert(int, HDiffrence)* 60 )+convert(int,MDiffrence)) else null end) as lessthan15
 from Pantau p

    left join PantauMSG pm
    on p.PantauID = pm.PantauID

    where PantauType = 'PT2' and PantauStatus <> 'PS1' and  
    (CAST(SCH_DATE AS DATE) = (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE(), 103) AS Expr1))
    group by  CONTRACTOR
```